# Функция bind, каррирование

Tags: javascript

1. Я правильно понял, что встроенный `bind` может выполнить каррирование ?
2. Написанный `bind` не может выполнить каррирование ?

```js
function mul(a, b) {
  return a * b;
};

var q = mul.bind(null, 2);
console.log(q(2,3))
```

```js
function mul(a, b) {
  return a * b;
};

function bind(func, context){
  return function(){
    return func.apply(context, arguments)
  };
};

var s = bind(mul, 'context', 3);

console.log(s(2))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В вашем примере `bind` не выполняет карринг. Он принимает 2 параметра (`func`, `context`). Вы нигде не привязываете аргументы.

Если я правильно понял, вы хотите сделать что-то вроде этого:

```js
function bind(func, context, ...args) {
    return function(...args2) {
      // Заметьте, что я использовал call вместо apply
      return func.call(context, ...args, ...args2);
    }
}

const mul = (a, b) => a * b;

console.log(mul(2, 3)); // 6
console.log(mul(3, 4)); // 12
console.log(mul(4, 5)); // 20

const double = bind(mul, null, 2);

console.log(double(2)); // 4
console.log(double(3)); // 6
console.log(double(5)); // 10
```